# Repressing Redirects and Alerts in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile

I'm aware of some `defineGetter`-ish prototypical functions and the like but what would I do to eradicate these problems?  See, I have to attach a certain variable to `window` to prevent a bothersome alert from opening and redirect from happening.  I have no access to the server but I don't think I ever will.  It's not necessary and I'd like to stop it all.  I've thought of redefining the ways these methods' return values are gotten and explicitly setting that variable and the latter has worked.  I'm writing an iPhone application that spoofs a user agent through cURL and JavaScript but the site **must** forcefully tell me there's a mobile version/app.  I'm tired of it and want it to stop but it's persistent.  I'm attempting to define the variable every time the page is loading but it's bothersome.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you're trying to do and what you have tried?

Comment: So you're writing an app that steals contents from someone else's site?

Comment: No; it's a friend's site that he lost ages ago and can't access. It's old but useful.